# Is it possible to programmatically get the current solution filename that is being used in Xamarin Studio/Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I have a few different solutionfiles (.sln) in my current project that each has a different name. When i work on one project i naturally open that .sln. Now I am wondering if it possible with code to get out the current solution file name that is being used or if its only possible to loop out all of the files, if that is even possible.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this information is not available at all, and even if you could, it probably only "works" while debugging with the solution open. Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Ok. I somehow need to figure out on how to aquire this name so i know what project im working on. I do have the name in my buildconfiguration too (DebugProjectOne or DebugProjectTwo). Maybe it's possible to get that piece of info out via code?

Comment: Please be careful not to mix "project" with "solution", which one are you looking for?

Comment: Solution* Sorry. These .sln files with their own buildconfiguration are in the same solution.

Comment: I am wondering if its possible to set a variable in a solution file and work with that..

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez Are you talking about the solution file name that contains the project(s) that is currently open in the IDE? If so, yes, via an IDE Addin : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/extending-visual-studio-mac

Comment: @SushiHangover Currently on the train. Will take a look asap. What im trying to accomplish is the following: before the functions inside `App.cs` runs i want to know what .sln file or build configuration is being built (both the .sln and config file has the name in it). With that name/info I will make functions accordingly.

Comment: I tried playing around with `AssemblyConfigurationAttribute` a bit but couldn't get anything out of that yet. What i've also looked at is to work with macros (variables) in the .sln files. I believe they are called macros.

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez That comment does not make any sense to me. If you have a "compile-time" configuration, add a compiler define and test for it via #if/#endif. If it is a "runtime" configuration, read a property from a config file. If it is a compile-time configuration that alters the runtime configuration, write a static variable value to `.cs` file during the build based upon the build configuration, but before the compile stage and then read that variable's value at runtime.

Comment: @SushiHangover Sorry for a delayed response. Whether its "Debug" or "Release" is not what im trying to find. In my sln files the Debug/Release  have their brandname in it too, so for instance if i work with the  `Projectone.sln` file then my buildconfigurations will look like this: `DebugProjectone` and `ReleaseProjectone`. If i instead work with the Projecttwo then it will change accordingly. In my app.cs i need to know now what project is running and on top of my head i can find out that through either .sln or the buildconfig name.

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez **`In my app.cs i need to know now what project is running`** :  Then you need to either alter `app.cs` during the build process, or alter a file (config) during the build process and read it in your `app.cs` to alter your code logic.

Comment: I understand what u mean but I am still unsure on how to execute it successfully. Do u have any examples/links? @SushiHangover

Comment: I am looking at the add-in which could be the solution for this, but i am still trying to find other options if its possible. Other places that i know of where i can seperate the projects and get the projectname is also via the current bundleid, current resources folder etc